# BUMP - django form request.POST.get('field-name', '') always empty

Tags: python, html, django, forms

Trying to get some values from a form but the parameters are always empty. here is the path from my urls.py:

```
url((r'^partners-email$'), views.partners_email, name="Partners Email"),
```

This is a simple form I have in the template:

```
<form method="POST" action="/partners-email">
        <input name="email" class="form-control" id="client-email">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and here is my function in views.py:

```
def partners_email(request):
    from_email = request.POST.get('email', '')
    print('MY_TAG: ' + from_email)
```

output is always:

"MYTAG: "

any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you added {% csrf_token %} after form tag?? You should.

Comment: whats print(request.POST)

Comment: Can you try sending a post request using `curl` or postman?

Comment: Yes, I had it before but inside the form had other divs. though that was the problem so I moved everything out. forgot the csrf_token. But I just added back inside the form with no difference

Comment: As @Vicmathur asked, did you check what is in `request.POST`? Also, is there any javascript applied on the email input field before the form is submitted?

Comment: print(request.POST) gives me an error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'QueryDict' objects. Don't know how to use curl sorry

Comment: whats output for print("My Tag :" , from_email)

Comment: no javascript on the whole page

Comment: whats output for print("My Tag :" , from_email) – ('My Tag :', '')

Comment: try request.POST.get('client-email', '')

Comment: your are typing something right in email input box ??

Comment: try request.POST.get('client-email', '') – The view fxnet.views.partners_email didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: your are typing something right in email input box ?? – yes ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

Your input elements don't have a `name` attribute so the browser will never send data for them.

Comment: <form method="POST" action="/partners-email">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="client-email">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
                </form> 

changed to this, still not working

Comment: whats print(request.POST)

Comment: <QueryDict: {}>

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="client-email">
```

Comment: What's the output of this print statement?

    print request.POST

Comment: <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: print request.method?